# Using javaScript for addition of multiple HTML items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm working on a website for a friend and on this website he has 4 different services for his customers. What he wants on the website is for the customer to be able to click on an icon and then next to it, it shows the price of said service. He also wants the customer to be able to click on other icons and the price increases depending on what they have selected.

**Example :**

> Service 1 = £60
>
> Service 2 = £80
>
> Service 3 = £100
>
> Service 4 = £120
>
> Customer clicks on Service 1 and the Total Price = £60.
>
> Customer also clicks Service 2 so Total Price = £140.

I have been trying for some time to figure out how to get this to work but I am not experienced at all with javaScript, so the best I have managed to come up with is this:

```
var service1 = 60;
var service2 = 80;
var service3 = 100;
var service4 = 120;

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = service1;
}

function myFunction2() {
document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = service2;
}

function myFunction3() {
document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = service3;
}

function myFunction4() {
document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = service4;
}
```

And of course my HTML has an onclick tag for each individual service, which then adds the price into the "generated" ID tag.

I'd be grateful for any help!
John

Comment: Please create an [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

## **Javascript code (using jQuery)**

```
var prices = [];
prices["service1"] = 60;
prices["service2"] = 80;
prices["service3"] = 100;
prices["service4"] = 120;

var generated = 0;

$(".add_service").click(function () {
  var desired_service = $(this).attr("id");
  generated += prices[desired_service];
  $("#generated").html("Total Price = £" + generated);
});
```

Try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cristian_g/7q5bLvwj/).

## **Explanation**

I have created four buttons with the same class and then I have binded an event handler for each button with the jQuery [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method. Then, it is possible to know which service does the user want by reading the id attribute of the button clicked (thanks to the jQuery `.attr()` method).